# Can Someone Help ME Convert Objective C to Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand the conversion and I'm just not getting it.

```
RVConfig *config = [RVConfig defaultConfig];
Rover *rover = [Rover setup:config];
[rover startMonitoring];
```

Here is what I have

```
RVConfig.defaultConfig()
Rover.setup(config: Rover(rover)
Rover.startMonitoring(Rover)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be something like this

```
let config = RVConfig.defaultConfig()
let rover = Rover.setup(config)
rover.startMonitoring()
```

Comment: Thank You. I just wasnt getting it.